# Setting a parameter on a join table in rails-admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

I have a model:

```
class Delivery < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :dropoff_points, :join_table => :delivery_dropoff_points
end
```

This model has a field `scheduled_date`.

This is a DeliveryDropoffPoint class:

```
class DeliveryDropoffPoint < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :delivery
   belongs_to :dropoff_point
end
```

I need to make sure that when I create a record in rails-admin on any given day the dropoff point gets one and only one delivery.

I tried to implement `before_save` filter:

```
class DeliveryDropoffPoint < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :delivery
  belongs_to :dropoff_point

  def set_scheduled_date
    self.scheduled_date = delivery.scheduled_date
  end

  before_save :set_scheduled_date

  validates_uniqueness_of :branch_floor, :scope => :scheduled_date, :message => "floor can only have one job assigned on a given day"
 end
```

However, `rails-admin` seemed to ignore it, regretfully. Is there any other way to set the value of a column in a join table when selecting the items in the select-box in rails-admin?

Thanks!

Comment: first of all, for what you created `DeliveryDropoffPoint`? `has_and_belongs_to_many` worked without middle model! second: your `set_scheduled_date` should be private method

Comment: or try `self.scheduled_date = self.delivery.scheduled_date`

Comment: middle model has to be there as it's a part of bigger part of the application.
adding `self.` and setting method to private didn't work - filter is still ignored by rails-admin

Comment: could you pry in `set_scheduled_date` and try to save object. Is `delivery.scheduled_date` defined? Associations works?

Comment: could you provide your `ropoff_point.rb` model? asoociations?
This callback and `set_scheduled_date` method should be in `ropoff_point.rb`.

Comment: the problem was solved by adding DeliveryDropoffPoints as a nested form - that way before_save filter was actually called on the contrary to the direct association.